# C++ function design

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, c++14, c++17

I came across the following question in multiple occasions this year but I don't have a clear answer to it: say I want to design a function that accumulates or in general builds something. I would need to declare the initial accumulator value (or an empty object in general), the problem is that whether I should initialize this value or object inside the function arguments with default value or should I initialize this thing inside the function body?

An example would be the following piece of function that split an sequential container into N equal size pieces (precondition: the pieces are splittable).
Is it a okay to write it in the following form

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
array<T, N> equal_split(const T& x, array<T, N> result = {}) {
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    std::copy(begin(x) + i * size(x) / 3, begin(x) + (i + 1) * size(x) / 3, std::back_inserter(result[i]));
  return result;
}
```

or is it better to write it as

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
array<T, N> equal_split(const T& x) {
  array<T, N> result = {};
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    std::copy(begin(x) + i * size(x) / 3, begin(x) + (i + 1) * size(x) / 3, std::back_inserter(result[i]));
  return result;
}
```

Comment: That's a matter of whether the user is supposed to be allowed to provide a different initial state or whether they shouldn't, isn't it?

Comment: @walnut Yes, from a user perspective this is indeed true. I am using it for my own algorithmic problem solving library, so I would like it to be as flexible as possible within the common design patterns. My concern is that putting the initial state in the function parameter is a bit weird, since it's not what a mathematical function would take..The only use case for such things I have seen before is the accumulator in a tail recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would need to declare the initial accumulator value

If it is just an implementation detail, then hide it from interface.

if different initial values make sense, then you might add it in interface.

In your example, signature would be:

```
template <std::size_t N, typename Container>
array<Container, N> equal_split(const Container&);
```

- Rename `T` to more meaningful `Container`
- `size_t N` first, to not have to provide deducible `Container`
- No default parameters, as initial value was just implementation detail.